# Lazily generate partial sums in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to produce a lazy list of partial sums and stop when I have found a "suitable" sum. For example, I want to do something like the following:

```
val str = Stream.continually {
  val i = Random.nextInt
  println("generated " + i)
  List(i)
}
str
  .take(5)
  .scanLeft(List[Int]())(_ ++ _)
  .find(l => !l.forall(_ > 0))
```

This produces output like the following:

```
generated -354822103
generated 1841977627
z: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(-354822103))
```

This is nice because I've avoided producing the entire list of lists before finding a suitable list. However, it's suboptimal because I generated one extra random number that I don't need (i.e., the second, positive number in this test run). I know I can hand code a solution to do what I want, but is there a way to use the core scala collection library to achieve this result without writing my own recursion?

The above example is just a toy, but the real application involves heavy-duty network traffic for each "retry" as I build up a map until the map is "complete".

EDIT: Note that even substituting `take(1)` for `find(...)` results in the generation of a random number even though the returned value `List()` does not depend on the number. Does anyone know why the number is being generated in this case? I would think `scanLeft` does not need to fetch an element of the iterable receiving the call to `scanLeft` in this case.

Comment: Isn't this caused by because the head is not lazy in Scala streams? (For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410659/scala-streams-not-acting-lazy) I think Scalaz has lazy streams for this purpose.

Comment: Is the `Stream` provided as input, or are you generating random numbers as you go? If the latter, then why not create a recursion that generates a random number with each iteration, checks the sum and runs another iteration if needed?

Comment: @benji, I could do this, but I was hoping to have a solution that is built purely from the existing abstractions in the standard scala libraries.